# Вылет PyTelegrambotAPI при запуске через консоль

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я хочу запустить бота Telebot (устанавливал через pip install PyTelegrambotAPI) через командную строку, но выдается такая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 60, in <module>
    bot = telebot.AsyncTeleBot(token)
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'AsyncTeleBot'
```

Бот запускается таким образом

```
bot = telebot.AsyncTeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать! Если не появились кнопки, напишите /start')
```

При запуске через PyCharm никаких ошибок не происходит. Что происходит не так?

Comment: запуск через PyCharm делаете из под виртуального окружения, а из консоли - без?

Comment: запуск в PyCharm делаю комбинацией Shift + F10, стандартной функцией
а в консоли вызываю в папке, где лежит проект, команду python main.py

Comment: python3 main.py попробуйте?

Comment: @Jack_oS сработало через py main.py

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо перейти в виртуальное окружение, для которого вы загружали пакеты. Для этого перейдите в папку вашего проекта (в ней должна быть подпапка типа venv) И выполните (в терминале/ cmd)

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Если у вас линукс
и

```
\env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Если это не помогло попытайтесь установить пакеты глобально:

```
pip install <name>
```

Подробнее о виртуальном окружении вы можете почитать в (этой)[https://habr.com/ru/post/157287/] Статье. Она немного устарела (python 3.3), но все принципы и основы остались те же.

Answer (score 0):

А pip установлен?

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Проверьте пошагово настройку через @BotFather, установку Python и pip, и перейдите к созданию Telegram бота, как описано здесь https://tproger.ru/translations/telegram-bot-create-and-deploy/.
Если не получается, там же вы можете найти другой вариант установки из исходников:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI.git
$ cd pyTelegramBotAPI
$ python setup.py install
```